# Ubuntu virtual machine to act as development server in Windows

Tags: server, virtualbox, apache2, lamp, webserver

I have a windows machine with two monitors and I am looking to get a development server running through virtualbox (LAMP stack with symfony framework/PHPStorm) so that I can:

1. Edit code out on the virtual machine running in a window one monitor
2. Have windows be served these pages by visiting `http://localhost:10080/` for example

Is there a way that I can make a generic VM image that I can use? Even better would be if I can put it on a USB stick and run th VM on any windows machine as a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly possible. I actually created a small script which sets up a virtual environment like you describe (although I use it purely as a server, I develop on my local machine). I put it on Github if you're interested:

https://github.com/Bartwillemsen/virtual-devbox

Basically what you need to do on your Ubuntu guest settings is create a second Network adapter and make it "host-only".

[image]

Then, on the first adapter (which is NAT by default, you can set some port redirections. I set mine up like this:

[image]

So with this, you can set up name based hosting with Apache. If you add the name of your website on you local computer's hostfile, you can access it with the url and portnumber like this: yourwebsite.local:8000 (in my case).

EDIT: You can define your shared folders in this screen:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gladen - it looks really promising :) I've been trying to get it to work today but after running `wget -O setup.sh http://goo.gl/vcJxVA` I have a copy of `setup.sh` in my direcory but not `aliases` and `serve.sh`. Could you guide me what I'm missing and how/why to define `/media/sf_php` as shared directory?

Comment: The setup.sh reels in and installs those files automatically. :) You should run the `setup.sh` file in your virtual machine and you should be good to go. The reason I created a shared directory was so that I could develop on my real machine and the files would automatically sync to my virtual machine. You can define a shared directory in the settings under "shared directories" tab. (I updated my answer with a screenshot).

Comment: Ow and make sure you attach the VirtualBox additions ISO via the `Devices` -> `Insert Guest Additions CD Image...` menu option.

Comment: Awesome - thanks so much Gladen....that's exactly what I was after :-) My only wish is that I figure out everything that happens from your github box of tricks!

Comment: No problem, glad it is of use for you. :) If you still have any questions regarding the script, or just things you're curious about, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi @Gladen - your setup is working great thanks - one question though - is there a 'shorthand' way I can access the virtual server rather than accessing pages using `localhost:8000/index.php` for example?

Comment: Sorry for late response.. What I do is make websites in apache using 'name based hosting'. It's quiet easy. Just generate a new virtual host using the `serve.sh` script that I provided.  Use it like this on your server: `sudo serve example.local directory`. The first parameter is the site URL, the second is the directory which should be the ducmentRoot. Then, just make sure to add the site to your hosts file on your real machine. Now you can access your site in the browser by typing `example.local:8000`!